# Can I make/receive phone calls with phone number attached to iPad's Verizon account?

Tags: apple-id, ipad

Just a few days ago I got an iPad Air 2 via Verizon. On the account, there is a phone number associated with the line for the tablet. Is that number functional? I guess what I mean is, can you answer phone calls or make calls with the number associated with the tablet? I've tried calling the number from a different number and nothing happens, but I'm not sure if it's just me.

If it is supposed to be a functional number then is there a way for me to add that number to an already existing Apple ID that is associated with my iPhone phone number?

Answer (score 2):

It serves only to make Verizon's back end provisioning work. You can't call to it, you can't call from it, you now just know it's not a "real live telephone number".

Pretty silly as there's a limited number of numbers that can exist in any one area code, but that's how things are engineered at present. Other carriers do the same thing, so it's not just vzw.